# How this code is working actually?

Tags: c

```
int main()
 {
  float a=4;
  int b=2;
  printf("%d\n",(a/b));
  printf("%f",(a/b));
  return 0;
 }
```

The first printf statement is printing different different values again an again.I know it is because i am using %d specifier for a float type number. But i don't know the actual working. 
Also,
when i am changing the first line:

```
int a=4;
```

then the second statement is printing

```
0.000000
```

again and again.Then why is the first printf in first code printing diffrent values but in second statement of second code, it is printing the same value?? 
Can anyone explain me?

Comment: Can you paste the output?

Comment: Using %d to print a float invokes undefined behavior. Therefore whatever the effect of the program is, it's correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dividing `int` by `int` yields an `int`. Dividing `float` by `int` yields a `float`.

For `int`, use `%d`. For `float`, use `%f`. If you mix them up, you get junk.

Comment: I already know this. The thing i want to know is why it is giving junk. How the float number is stored in memory. And when we are using a specifier %d then how it is interpreting it as an integer. Can you tell me how specifiers work?

Comment: What you're doing is undefined, which means it's up to implementation specific details, and can do anything (including crashing and worse). If you want the details, use a debugger to print the memory bit by bit, see how an integer is stored and how a float is stored, and see what you get when looking at a float as if it was an integer.

Answer (score 3):

`a/b` will give you a `float` (and get promoted to `double`) value. Printing it with `%d` specifier will invoke undefined behavior.

> Then why is the first `printf` in first code printing different values but in second statement of second code, it is printing the same value?? Can anyone explain me?

This is because of undefined behavior. In this case sometimes you may get the result you expected, sometime result is what I expected and sometimes what compiler expect.

Comment: `a/b` is a `float` but it's promoted to `double`. +1 for mentioning UB anyway.

Comment: It is undefined across environments. May be OP asking why this is not consistent in same environment. May be this code on his environment making an access to a memory area not initialized and hence giving different results in every pass? However, the result is consistent over different passes in my system (Emphasizing UB).